# Support for designated struct initializers on Windows?

Tags: c, porting

We are porting a Linux driver to Windows. In Linux global structures are initialized in the following way.Assuming the structure has 4 elements where only 3 are initialized.

```
struct globalInitialize init = {
     .a = 10,
     .b = 20,
     .d = 30,
};
```

This is fine with Linux, but when directly used in WINDOWS we get compilation errors and it should be modified as below

```
struct globalInitialize init = {
     10,
     20,
     NULL,
     30,
};
```

Is there any way to suppress these compilation errors in windows without any changes to code. Let me know for more details.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the same compiler.

Comment: This is not a problem of Linux/Windows, but of gcc/VC++ (the latter doesn't support C99, which is required for designated initializers).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: honestly, I wouldn't build Windows drivers with anything but the toolchain supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - It is standards compliant, provided the standard is C99, which Microsoft apparently has little interest in.

Comment: @asveikau: yup, I forgot about designated initializers; and yes, Microsoft stated more than once that they aren't interested in C99.

Comment: You can still use `gcc` from MinGW or something similar.

Comment: @Jori You should format your comment as an answer!

Comment: @MatteoItalia Microsoft has actually changed their stance on C99 and have implemented some support in Visual Studio 2013.  According to [this VS team blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/09/09/visual-studio-2013-rc-now-available.aspx) designated initialisers are included, which makes me wonder if OP is compiling as C++ rather than C (or is maybe using an older VS).

Comment: I saw the release notes for VS2013, including the "better C99 support" tag, which I found so hysterical coffee nearly shot from my nose. It almost seemed like  "yeah, we know its 14 years later, but hey, were getting there..." was somehow a gilded feather in their cap. But alas, its better than it was before, so I guess I should be thankful for that. =P. Can't wait until 2025 when they're just about have that C11-compliance nailed down.

Comment: @NigelHarper: the WDK isn't always aligned with the latest release of Visual Studio, typically the compiler is about one version before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is obligatory for your development team to use the Visual C++ compiler from Microsoft, but there are `gcc` ports available for Windows. An example of such port is [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), or if you want an entire POSIX application deployment platform you could look at [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

If you have to use Visual C++ , you should update to/buy [the right version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/09/09/visual-studio-2013-rc-now-available.aspx) supporting these 'new' 'C11' features (thanks Nigel Harper).

> Supports ISO C11 language features including _Bool, compound literals,
>   designated initializers, and mixing declarations with code.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable info.